# Check if property quantity is > 1 then push price * quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager

the function below loops through the properties of the objects in `var input` which is for example

```
[{
    name: 'Nagellack 15 ml 2 2',
    id: '1057290002',
    price: '1.9',
    brand: 'a.o.n.',
    quantity: 1
}, {
    name: 'Ceramic Nail Lacquer 6 ml Coral Reef Coral Reef',
    id: '1027410001',
    price: '6.9',
    brand: 'Artdeco',
    quantity: 1
}]
```

and pushes new objects into

```
products_list []
```

I'm trying to set up a condition which checks when the quantity of an object is  > 1 and then multiplies the price with the quantity. The issue here is, that I only get the price of one product although there is a quantity of 2.

I don't know which is the best place in the code set up the condition.

```
function() {
    var input = {{dl_purchase_products}};
    var products_list = [];
        for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        products_list.push({
            id: input[i].id.slice(0,6),
            price: input[i].price,  <---- this should be the price for 2 
            quantity: input[i].quantity
        });
        }
    return products_list;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Best regards, 
Anton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the price by the quantity.

Comment: Such a complex description an such an easy solution. Kinda embarrassing :) Thanks for your help! @Scott Hunter